# Magento - Collecting and displaying full cc details

Tags: magento

Im running Magento 1.7.0.2 and I was looking around to see if there was a way to have magento display the full CC details used to place an order.

I know by default magento DOES NOT store or diplay all 16 digits along with their expiration dates, is there any way in doing so? Editing the core perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind tho storing the full 16 digit number is a PCI compliancy issue.

Comment: @Jeff Im aware of the PCI compliance, but instead of having customer build a custom product over the phone we decided to keep our orders internal but offer them to build it online and then have us charge it after the custom product is accepted by our provider

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to enable the Saved Credit Card payment method to capture the full credit card number. You also need the encryption key that you got at the time of installing Magento to retrieve the full number in this case.

More information here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9221/